Express.js session not found
I'm encountering an issue with session management in my Express.js application. After a successful login, the session is created and stored in MongoDB, but subsequent requests show "Session not found or user not authenticated" errors.
I've verified that the session middleware is properly configured, and the session data seems to be stored correctly. What could be causing this issue, and how can I troubleshoot it effectively?
here is my App.js
const store = new MongoDBStore({
  uri: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mentorship',
  collection: 'sessions',
});

// Express session middleware
app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: store,
    cookie: { maxAge: 3600000 }, // Session expires in 1 hour (adjust as needed)
  })
);

// Test route
app.use("/api", apirouter);

and here is my controller
  getUserInfo: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      console.log('Request received for fetching user info');
  
      if (req.session && req.session.user) {
        console.log('Session found. User is authenticated');
  
        const { _id, email } = req.session.user;
        console.log('Fetching user details from the database');
        console.log('User ID from session:', _id); // Log user ID from session
        console.log('User email from session:', email); // Log user email from session
        const user = await User.findById(_id);
  
        if (!user) {
          console.log('User not found in the database');
          return res.status(404).json({ message: 'User not found' });
        }
  
        const userInfo = { _id: user._id, email: user.email, username: user.username };
        console.log('User info fetched successfully');
        res.status(200).json(userInfo); // Return user info stored in session along with username
      } else {
        console.log('Session not found or user not authenticated');
        res.status(401).json({ message: 'User not authenticated' });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching user info:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server error' });
    }
  }

always : "Session not found or user not authenticated"

Sounds like you forgot to implement authentication on top of session.
Storing session does not automatically put user object into your session.
That's why this condition if (req.session && req.session.user) { is false and as a result you see console.log('Session not found or user not authenticated');.
First you need to implement authentication flow in your app. You can use example from session docs.
Alternatively you can you can use passport.js

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review

Make sense. I’ll update it asap

Thank you for your input. I appreciate your suggestion regarding authentication and session management.
but I do have authentication implemented in my application. When a user logs in successfully, their credentials are verified, and a session is created with a session cookie that should persist for subsequent requests.

oh, could you please update the question with authentication implementation details? this is relevant to the question and might help to investigate the issue
